# Match instances of words and count adjacent numbers

Tags: excel

I have two columns

First column a list of different alphanumeric barcodes, the second the stock sold for each of them.

For example

```
AC06  2
AC03  4
AC03  3
DEF45  5
```

I can use sumif to find words and total it that way. But it's a big list and I dont know how to replicate the sumif quickly. So itll find all instances of column a barcode total the numbers adjacent and move onto the next barcode.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about a Pivot Table?

Comment: What about subtotals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is exactly a Pivot Table. You can resume common data, and make some calculations (like sum). I guess your data is like this:

[image]

You can resume your data inserting a Pivot Table like this (Barcodes into rows section and Stock into values section, sum operation):

[image]

To learn about Pivot Tables check [Pivot Tables](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of unique Bar codes using "Remove Duplicates " in "Data" tab. On that unique list of bar code apply sumif function or as mentioned above Pivot is also a good alternative.